# How to set condition for object's property in class java

Tags: java, class, object

I have a program to enter the student's name, gender, grade, and rank
Here is my code:

> public class Exercise_W28 {
> String name;
> String Sex;
> int Score;
> String ratting;
>
> ```
> public Exercise_W28(String name, String Sex,
>                int Score, String ratting)
> {
>     this.name = name;
>     this.Sex = Sex;
>     this.Score = Score;
>     this.ratting = ratting;
> }
>
> public String getName()
> {
>     return name;
> }
>
> public String getSex()
> {
>     return Sex;
> }
>
> public int getScore()
> {
>     return Score;
>     
> }
>
> public String getratting()
> {
>   
>     return ratting;
> }
>
> public String toString()
> {
>     return("Name: "+ this.getName()+
>           ".\nSex: "+ this.getSex()+
>           ".\nScore: "+ this.getScore()+
>           ".\nRank: "+ this.getratting()+"."
>           );         
> }
>
> public static void main(String[] args)
> {
>   
>   Exercise_W28 std = new Exercise_W28("Jullien","male", 9, "RankA");
>     System.out.println(std.toString());
> } }
> ```

Now I want to not put the rank in, but based on the score to determine the rank 1~5 : rankC, 5~7: rankD, 8~10: rankA.
I just learned about classes in java and I don't know how to handle it

Comment: Read about if statements and numeric comparison operators.

Comment: Hint : Create a setter for rank, that receives the score and computes the rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `Rank` from constructor and basis on the score passed, initialize the Rank value in constructor itself !

For e.g.

```
public Exercise_W28(String name, String Sex,
               int Score)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.Sex = Sex;
    this.Score = Score;
    // if(score == 5) 
  {
ratting="Rank C" ; //so on and so forth 
}
```

If the logic is too long, consider defining it in another method which returns Rank in `String` form!

Comment: the result is Rank: null. It doesn't work